# Valid values for `\newfont`

Tags: fonts, tex-core

I'm using a template for a thesis and want to change the font of the chapter number. The template ("classicthesis") uses:

```
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{eurb10 scaled 7000}
```

with using Eulerfont. I'd like to use a sans serif font, e.g. Alegreya.

```
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{AlegreyaSansOsF scaled 7000}
```

doesn't work. Even using a built-in font, e.g.

```
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{phv scaled 7000}
```

gives me the error, that the font is not loadable. So what is a valid value for the font in `\newfont` and where can I find the values for custom fonts? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TeX command `\newfont` expects the name of a TFM file. You can either look into the suitable FD file or into `TEXMF/fonts/tfm/huerta/alegreya` to find all availalbe TFM files. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{AlegreyaSans-Regular-osf-ot1 scaled 7000}
\begin{document}

{\chapterNumber 1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `\newfont`. The `classicthesis` package does, but it shouldn't as well.

```latex
\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{\fontsize{70}{0}\usefont{OT1}{Alegreya-OsF}{m}{n}}
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{\fontsize{70}{0}\usefont{OT1}{Alegreya-OsF}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]